# Differences between mod_cache and memcached

Tags: django, apache2, memcached

i want to know what are the differences between mod_cache and memcached. I've work in a django site, so i'm using mod_wsgi in apache2. **My question is should cache behind apache or django-memcached ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a simple content cache, where your responses are cached, then mod_cache seems like an easier bet.  It's really just meant to cache responses for you to either memory or disk.

Memcached is an entirely different beast in my opinion.  It works entirely in memory, but it can work across multiple machines, and your backend layer can access results from the cache.  So your backend can put things in the cache so it doesn't have to do any expensive work again.  It goes beyond what a normal content cache like mod_cache gives you.